# Unity3d crash on Launching on Ubuntu

Tags: unity, linux

I have a problem that bugged me for quite some time now
I'm trying to Install Ubity3d on Ubuntu
I Followed some instructions that i've found after some research
I downloaded and installed UnityHub and the latest release (UnitySetup-2019.1.0f2) that i found on [Unity on Linux: Release Notes and Known Issues](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/page-2)

and i moved the installed unity file from **Home** to **opt** folder and made it run on command *unity3d* and here is what i did exactly

```
sudo mv Unity-2019.1.0f2 /opt/Unity3D
sudo ln -s /opt/Unity3D/Editor/Unity /usr/bin/unity3d
```

and the problem is that every time i open Unity editor (via both the command line and UnityHub) the unity Launcher appears for moments to proccess and then crashes and the editor doesn't open and the error changes everytime i try to open the program here are 3 forms of errors that appeared to me, here is the first

```
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
[Unity Package Manager (Upm)]
Parent process [5258] was terminated
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and the second

```
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
(unity-editor:6651): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_file_chooser_widget_set_current_name: assertion 'priv->action == 
GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SAVE || priv->action == 
GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_CREATE_FOLDER' failed
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
[Unity Package Manager (Upm)]
Parent process [6651] was terminated
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

the third is

```
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
[0616/110743:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(161)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See     
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
[0616/110744:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(207)] Gtk: 
gtk_window_present_with_time: assertion 'GTK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
USER@USER:~$ [Unity Package Manager (Upm)]
Parent process [7583] was terminated
```

and stuck on that....
well i know that there's something wrong with GTK but i have no experiace with it and i didn't find anything useful on this matter on google

> OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTC

Answer (score 1):

"Running without SUID sandbox" -- I've had this too. You need to make sure you have full permissions (777) of the Unity folder and its subfolders and files contained within them.